# Angular Build Error : Please add a @NgModule annotation - ng-click-outside?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

> ERROR in Unexpected value 'ClickOutsideModule in
> E:/vmsui/node_modules/ng-click-outside/lib_commonjs/click-outside.module.d.ts'
> imported by the module 'AppModule in E:/vmsui/src/app/app.module.ts'.
> Please add a @NgModule annotation.

**App.Module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { ClickOutsideModule } from 'ng-click-outside';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ClickOutsideModule  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Html**

```
<div class="notification-wrapper">
          <div class="notification-btn" (click)="openNotification(!showNotification)">
            <div class="fa fa-bell"></div><span style="margin-bottom: 10px;">{{unseenCount}}</span>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="showNotification" class="notification-content" (clickOutside)="openNotification(false)"
          [exclude]="'.notification-btn'">
            <div class="notification-header">
              <span class="mdi mdi-settings"></span>
              <span class="label">Notifications</span>
            </div>
            <div class="test">
              <div style="margin-left: 10px;" *ngFor="let val of notifications" >
                <a> {{val.msg}} </a><i class="stop-button" (click)="myStop()" style="cursor:pointer;float: right;margin-right:10px;" title="Stop" class="fa fa-times-circle-o text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
showNotification: boolean;  
openNotification(state: boolean) {
    this.showNotification = state;
  }
```

Code is working fine. What the problem is when taking production build I'm getting Please add a `@NgModule` annotation for `ClickOutsideModule`. Its imported properly in `app.module.ts`. but The build is failed with error.

I tried this [Link](https://touwin10.com/tutorials/XgIySYANbecEoOMXsMFf/how-to-make-a-drop-down-notification-menu-in-angular-2%2B)